# Execute js.erb only if some condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am not very confident with cofeescript or js so I am a little bit confused. I have a quick editing functionality which sends an AJAX request and updates the database. Currently I'm manually changing the edited place and display it but it looks like a cheat to me and the badges won't update! I want to re render my specific post. I've given my `<li>` a `data-id` attribute so I can get it my post by `Post.find($(#li).data('id'))` (not very sure if it works but there should be a way to pass variables. Now the main problem is that I have other scripts on my posts/index.js.erb that I don't want to be executed. I only want a part which relates to this to be executed upon AJAX success (which is in another file) or `$('#form').submit`. Now I have no idea how to achieve this! It sounds like a simple problem but my lack of knowledge on how to all other scripts and restrict part of those scripts is limited.

**EDIT** Any suggestions on how to call my index.js.erb from another coffeescript or js file? Or send parameters and use them in that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this Ajax is executed on a onchange event, then you'd pass a value that you can later evaluate on your .js.erb file. For example:

Lets say the event happens on the onchange of a text_field_tag

```
<%= text_field_tag(:for_event, "", :onchange=> "TheAjax('identifier')") %>
```

Then you declare a function (TheAjax for this example)

```
<script>
   function TheAjax(identifier){
     var dataString = 'the_id='+identifier;
     $.ajax(
       {      
     type: "GET",  
     url: "/your_view_name/your_method",  
     data: dataString  
       }); 
      return false;
   }    
</script>
```

That Ajax will pass a param called "the_id" with a value of "identifier" (The value is passed as a param when you call the function in the onchange method.

Now, in your js.erb file (which should be linked to one of you controller method, the show method for example, you can evaluate the value of the "the_id" param, and then decide which actions to take. For example:

(Show method in your controller)

```
def show
 @my_identifier = params[:the_id] (session var so you'd access it on your js.erb file)
end
```

Your js.erb file

```
<% case @my_identifier %>
   <% when 'identifier' %>
      Here you put whatever part of your JS you want to execute ONLY when the condition is met.
   <% else %>
      Whatever else you want to execute when the previous conditions are not met
<% end %>
```

ALSO keep in mind that if you want to handle database updating you can also do a 'case' in your controller and manage your database changes when the condition is met.

Comment: Yes it is executed `on('change')`

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks man I actually did this before looking here but great answer. It's more complete and neater than what I did.